# Converting between different implementations of abstract class with generic convert method

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

I have an abstract class which contains a number of fixed objects, typically Dictionaries and Lists of various types. There are then abstract methods for ReadData and WriteData. I then have two different implementations of this abstract class, one which writes data according to a "text record" standard and the other XML against a defined XML schema.

The two implementations are therefore identical, apart from different ways of reading and writing.

What I now want to do is to read in data in format 1, and then write it as format 2. I can do this quite easily by writing methods such as `.ToFormat2()` and `.ToFormat1()` in the respective classes, and probably `.FromFormat2()` and `.FromFormat1()` if I want completeness. But these routines are essentially the same, and I am thinking ahead to the (not too distant) future when I am going to need Format 3, and don't want to have to merrily implement two or more identical "To" methods in each class. It's a waste of time, is difficult to debug / change, and just isn't nice.

So I've been trying to write a generic converter within the abstract class. The following code illustrates the principle of what I have done so far:

```
public abstract class Test
{
    public string Type;
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dic1;
    public Dictionary<string, int> Dic2;

    public abstract void Read(string fileName);
    public abstract void Write(string fileName);

    public T ConvertTo<T>() where T : Test
    {
        T x = new T();
        if (x.Type.Equals(this.Type)) { return this; }
        x.Dic1 = this.Dic1;
        x.Dic2 = this.Dic2;
        return x;
    }
}

public class Format1 : Test
{
    // Constructor
    public Format1() { Type = "Format1"; Dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string>(); Dic2 = new Dictionary<string, int>(); }

    // Concrete implementations of abstract Read and Write for "Format1"
    public override void Read(string fileName) { /* do reading stuff */ }
    public override void Write(string fileName) { /* do writing stuff */ }
}

public class Format2 : Test
{
    // Constructor
    public Format2() { Type = "Format2"; Dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string>(); Dic2 = new Dictionary<string, int>(); }

    // Concrete implementations of abstract Read and Write for "Format2"
    public override void Read(string fileName) { /* do reading stuff */ }
    public override void Write(string fileName) { /* do writing stuff */ }
}
```

But the compiler doesn't like this. I am getting an error when I declare `x` to be a new `T` because it doesn't have the new() constraint, and I cannot return `this` because I can't implicitly cast `Test.Test` to `T`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would consider instead creating a wrapper round your object instead of using inheritance for this. Consider that the class shouldn't really care how it is loaded/saved (single responsibility principle). If you instead created an  ITestPersistance that had Save() and Load() methods, you can contain all the logic in here without abusing inheritance. This means you can add a new implementation of ITestPersistance (i.e. Format3TestPersistance) without changing any of the other code... This could be extended to ITestFormat and ITestPersistance if you want to be even more flexible...

Comment: @Milney. Um, yes. Rather obvious now you've pointed it out. Got a bit lost in the inheritance there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since abstract classes (and interfaces) cannot contain a contract about the type’s constructor, just specifying that your type `T` is of type `Test` is not enough to guarantee to the compiler that there will be a (default/parameterless) constructor.

So in order to guarantee that, you will have to expand your generic type argument constraint to include that condition:

```
public T ConvertTo<T>() where T : Test, new()
```

Note the `new()` which essentially says “of a type that has a default constructor”.

---

After doing that, you will run into another issue that tells you that `this` cannot be converted to `T`. You will have to perform an explicit type conversion there:

```
if (x.Type.Equals(this.Type)) { return (T)this; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your `ConvertTo<T>` method like this

```
public T ConvertTo<T>() where T : Test, new()
```

Then you'll get another error I guess because you have to cast the return value like this

```
if (x.Type.Equals(this.Type)) { return (T)this; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can require all `Test` classes to have a parameterless constructor, so that a new instance can be created:

```
public T ConvertTo<T>() where T : Test, new()
{
    T x = new T();
    if (x.Type.Equals(this.Type)) { return (T) this; }
    x.Dic1 = this.Dic1;
    x.Dic2 = this.Dic2;
    return x;
}
```

EDIT: If you don't want / can't have parameterless constructors, you can separate the Read/Write methods from the data (dictionaries and lists) like this:

```
public interface IReadWriter
{
    void Read(Test test, string filenName);
    void Write(Test test, string filenName);
}

public class Test
{
    public string Type;
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dic1;
    public Dictionary<string, int> Dic2;
    public IReadWriter readWriter;

    public Test(IReadWriter readWriter)
    {
        this.readWriter = readWriter;
    }

    public void Read(string fileName)
    {
        readWriter.Read(this, fileName);
    }

    public void Write(string fileName)
    {
        readWriter.Write(this, fileName);
    }

    public Test WithReadWriter(IReadWriter other)
    {
        Test x = new Test(other);
        //if (x.Type.Equals(this.Type)) { return this; }
        x.Dic1 = this.Dic1;
        x.Dic2 = this.Dic2;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can change things around a little so that I do have parameterless constructors, by adding some methods to change some of the protected things that my constructors set, but I'll spend a bit of time understanding your code here a bit, as I sense that might be better in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) maybe  help you: 
Apply the new constraint to a type parameter when your generic class creates new instances of the type and When you use the new() constraint with other constraints, it must be specified last

```
    public T ConvertTo<T>() where T : Test,new()
    {
        T x = new T();
        if (x.Type.Equals(this.Type)) { return (this as T) ; }
        x.Dic1 = this.Dic1;
        x.Dic2 = this.Dic2;
        return x;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have marked @poke as the answer, because he answered the question that I was asking about a generic converter. However, I also took on board the comment from @Milney pointing out that I was inheriting something that shouldn't really be inherited. So this is probably a better way of doing the same thing, which I'm posting for completeness sake.

It has all of the interesting bits in a class called `DataModel`, and this is then placed into the interface. Constructors to each of the classes allow me to pass a DataModel in one of the overloads, so that I can easily create a new format based on all the data in a previous one.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Format1 f1 = new Format1("5.10");
        f1.Data.Dic1.Add("Greet", "Hello World");
        f1.Data.Dic2.Add("RepeatGreet", 10);
        f1.Write("f1");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------");

        Format2 f2 = new Format2("2.1","general",f1.Data);
        f2.Data.Dic1.Add("Goodbye", "See you later, Alligator");
        f2.Data.Dic2.Add("RepeatBye", 1);
        f1.Write("f1");
        f2.Write("f2");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public interface IDataFormat
{
    void Read(string filename);
    void Write(string filename);
    string Type { get; }
    string Version { get; }
    DataModel Data { get; }
}

public class DataModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dic1;
    public Dictionary<string, int> Dic2;

    // Constructor
    public DataModel() { Dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string>(); Dic2 = new Dictionary<string, int>(); }
}

public class Format1 : IDataFormat
{
    public string Type { get; }
    public string Version { get; }
    public DataModel Data {get; }

    // Constructors
    public Format1(string version) : this(version, new DataModel()) { }
    public Format1(string version, DataModel data) { Type = "Format1"; Version = version; Data = data; }

    // Concrete implementations of abstract Read and Write for "Format1"
    public void Read(string fileName) { /* do reading stuff */ }
    public void Write(string fileName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("WRITING " + fileName +" IN FORMAT1:");
        Console.WriteLine("Type: " + Type + "\tVersion: " + Version);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in Data.Dic1) { Console.WriteLine("\t" + kvp.Key + "\t" + kvp.Value); }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in Data.Dic2) { Console.WriteLine("\t" + kvp.Key + "\t" + kvp.Value); }
    }
}

public class Format2 : IDataFormat
{
    // Properties
    public string Type { get; }
    public string SubType { get; set; }     // A property unique to this class
    public string Version { get; }
    public DataModel Data { get; }

    // Constructors. 
    // Including a constructor which is unique to this class because it uses a unique property of this class
    public Format2(string version) : this(version, "", new DataModel()) { }
    public Format2(string version, DataModel data) : this( version, "", data) { }
    public Format2(string version, string subType, DataModel data) { Type = "Format2"; Version = version; SubType = subType; Data = data; }

    // Concrete implementations of abstract Read and Write for "Format2"
    public void Read(string fileName) { /* do reading stuff */ }
    public void Write(string fileName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("WRITING " + fileName + " IN FORMAT2:");
        Console.WriteLine("Type: " + Type + "........Version: " + Version);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in Data.Dic1) { Console.WriteLine("........" + kvp.Key + "........" + kvp.Value); }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in Data.Dic2) { Console.WriteLine("........" + kvp.Key + "........" + kvp.Value); }
    }
}
```